# Disable a link click event when the browser JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript

I'm displaying a link
`<a href="some-url">Click me</a>`

I want the user can can click on the above link and it should redirect the user to specified url if the browser javascript is enabled. 
And if the browser javascript is disabled then it should do nothing?

Is it possible?

Comment: href will work regardless of javascript being enabled or not...

Answer (score 0):

Generate the link with JavaScript in the first place.

If JavaScript isn't supported, then it won't create the link.